# Показать данные в ячейке таблицы

Tags: html

Вывожу карту в виде html таблицы. Данных много и вместить их в ячейку нереально. Как сделать так, чтобы при наведении на ячейку показывалось типа подсказки с данными? Может есть специальный тег, или с помощью js.

Comment: в title впихнуть?

Comment: доп тег в ячейке

Comment: Подошло. Правда показывается с задержкой, что не очень радует.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, используй [jqueryUI tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip). Дополнительную информацию можно загружать в alt, title и data.